# batch copying excel file with wildcard in name doesn't copy contents in file

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file to copy and rename a file on a public directory to another public directory. The file is normally about 1600kb in size but copied only has 1kb. If I change the wildcard in the name to the real name I get the whole file copied. Problem is the file name changes after every update e.g. Name 3.25.13, Name 4.12.13 e.t.c so I have to use a wildcard unless there is any other way you can tell me, which will be very much appreciated. Here is the code for the batch:

```
c:
cd U:\Sourcing\Vendor Demand Planning\Master CPFR\

copy "U:\Sourcing\Vendor Demand Planning\Master CPFR\Master CPFR*.xlsx" "U:\Sourcing\Vendor Demand Planning\Pricing Project\Master CPFR.xlsx"
```

Comment: do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dir /o:-d` to get the newest matching file.

```
cd /d "U:\Sourcing\Vendor Demand Planning\Master CPFR\"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /o:-d "Master CPFR*.xlsx"') do (
    copy "%%I" "..\Pricing Project\Master CPFR.xlsx"
    exit /b
)
```

If you've got more to your script, just replace `exit /b` with a `goto label` and put a `:label` somewhere after the `for` loop.  You only want your loop to execute once, then break.